# Doing an intervention analysis using ARIMA model of stock data in R

Tags: r, time-series, xts, arima

I'm having some issues with my intervention analysis. I'm modelling the effect on Nvidia's (NVDA) closing price when they announced their deep learning super computer in April 2016. I've added a dummy variable that is 0 before the intervention date, and 1 after, and added it as a regressor in my model. My probelm is that I can't make sense of the output, since I never get anything significant from the intervention coefficient. I can't tell if I'm doing anything wrong. Here's my code:

```
rm(list=ls())
library('ggplot2'); library('forecast'); library('tseries'); library('xts'); library(quantmod) ; library(lmtest)

start <- as.Date("2005-01-01")
end <- as.Date("2018-10-01")

getSymbols("NVDA", src = "yahoo", from = start, to = end)
plot(NVDA[, "NVDA.Close"], main = "NVIDIA")


# Adding dummy intervention variable

intDate<-as.Date("2016-04-05") #  sets the intervention Date  
closing = NVDA[, "NVDA.Close"]
closing$Intervention = 0
for (i in 1:nrow(closing)){
  if (index(closing[i,1]) < intDate){
    closing[i,"Intervention"] = 0
  }
  if(index(closing[i,1]) >= intDate){
    closing[i,"Intervention"] = 1
  }
}

model<-auto.arima(closing[,"NVDA.Close"], xreg = closing[,"Intervention"])

model
coeftest(model)

dates = as.Date(index(closing),"YYYY-MM-DD")
fittedVal = xts(fitted.values(model), dates)

plot(NVDA[,"NVDA.Close"], col = "blue", type = "l")
lines(fittedVal, col = "red", type = "l")
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent a few more hours messing around with the model parameters. Instead of using a "pure jump" intervention variable (0's and 1's), I tried a gradually increasing effect over 200 periods. This helped capture the intervention effect and make all of the coefficients significant, but I can't really use the results since the model's residuals aren't normally distributed. Here's the code I used:

```
rm(list=ls())
library('ggplot2'); library('forecast'); library('tseries'); library('xts'); library(quantmod) ; library(lmtest)

start <- as.Date("2005-01-01")
end <- as.Date("2018-10-01")

getSymbols("NVDA", src = "yahoo", from = start, to = end)
plot(NVDA[, "NVDA.Close"], main = "NVIDIA")


# Adding dummy intervention variable

intDate<-as.Date("2016-04-05") 
closing = NVDA[, "NVDA.Close"]
periods = 200
count = 0
closing$Intervention = 0
for (i in 1:nrow(closing)){
  if (index(closing[i,1]) < intDate){
    closing[i,"Intervention"] = 0
  }
  if(index(closing[i,1]) >= intDate){
    count = count + 1
    if(count<=periods){
      closing[i,"Intervention"] = count*0.025
    }
    if(count>periods){
      closing[i,"Intervention"] = periods*0.025
    }

  }
}

model<-auto.arima(closing[,"NVDA.Close"], xreg = closing[,"Intervention"])

model
coeftest(model)

dates = as.Date(index(closing),"YYYY-MM-DD")
fittedVal = xts(fitted.values(model), dates)

plot(NVDA[,"NVDA.Close"], col = "blue", type = "l")
lines(fittedVal, col = "red", type = "l")
```